# Resizing an image to be centered

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox, react-native-image

I have an image like so:

[image]

I am trying to make a 100x100 square and then centering that image inside it. I am able to get the 100x100 square with this code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/iex/api/logos/GOOGL.png', }}
            style={styles.image}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  image: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100
  }
});

export default App;
```

However that cuts off the image:

[image]

Is there a way I can set a 100x100 width/height, but allow the image to resize as necessary to fit and be centered inside the square? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this? Its called resizeMode from React Native.

[image]

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  imageContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1
  },
  image: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }
});
```

Comment: I had no idea about `resizeMode`, I somehow missed it in the docs. Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem mate!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link, for my has been very useful! is the **jQuery Image Cente**r. *Centers an image by moving, cropping and filling spaces inside its parent container. Maintains aspect ratio*.

http://boxlight.github.com/bl-jquery-image-center

Comment: I'm using react native, so can't really use a web based library like this

Answer (score 0):

For resize see the doc of resizeMode and resizeMethod in doc.